# How to pass current value of Ui form field in js file

Tags: javascript, uicomponent, model, requirejs

I want to pass the value of checkbox in custom js file, I am using UI component to create a chechbox.
So I have to pass this value to js file and then use that value in Model.
I am not able to pass the value

```
<field name="is_new_category_allowed">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Do you want to create new Category</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. You have to add a custom js file via the validation

```
<field name="is_new_category_allowed">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Do you want to create new Category</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="custom-check-validation" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> <!-- Here added custom validation -->
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

> 2. Create js file for get value of field in js Validation file Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom_validation.js

```
 require(
        [
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
            'jquery',
            'mage/translate'
    ], function(validator, $){

        validator.addRule(
            'custom-check-validation',
            function (value) {                          
                if(value == 1){   //Here you will get your field's value                      
                    return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            ,$.mage.__('Custom validation message.')
        );
        
});
```

> 3. Add js file when create new category Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_category_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>      
        <link src="Vendor_Module::js/custom_validation.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

> 4. Add js file when edit category Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_category_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>      
        <link src="Vendor_Module::js/custom_validation.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

If you have any question please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to pass js pass value to my custom model?

Comment: Hi @Mital Shah, Can we call this validation <item name="custom-check-validation" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> in our custom php model?